# How to use env variables with nx expo?

Tags: expo, environment-variables, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx.dev

I have created this file : `.local.env`  in the `my-app/apps/app-test` directory. The file has the the following content for environment variable:

```
NX_API_URL=https://www.test.com/test
```

How do I make this environment variable usuable in my nx expo project?
I have tried accessing it with `const path = process.env.NX_API_URL` but it doesn't seem to work. I get undefined as a value.